# Reaching website through IIS from an other computer

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7

I think I'm almost done with this problem but there is something off. Perhaps you guys can help me out.

I've created a website which I can reach through `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\KLABrowser\publish.htm`.

I've created a website through IIS called `KLABrowser`. The `http` binding is listed on port `1111`, with `*` as IP adress.

When going to `http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:1111/KLABrowser/publish.htm`, I get a `Cannot find page` error. When I go to `http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/KLABrowser/publish.htm`, I get a blank page but no error. When I hit the first link (the psychical path), I get to see the website.

What am I missing? What should I configure so that I can reach the website through my IP on an other computer in the local network?

Comment: Can you reach it via localhost:1111 from the server itself? If so, then check your firewall rules to make sure that port is open to allow http traffic.

Comment: @AaronS Only `localhost:1111` returns a white page. When putting `/KLABrowser/` or `/KLABrowser/publish.htm` after ith, I get a page not found...

Comment: Have you mapped the port 1111 to listen to http traffic?

Comment: @Rajesh How can I achieve that?

Comment: You would need to use the netsh command via command prompt. Ex: netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1111/ user=\everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer provided the solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440144/iis-7-5-under-win7-prof-64bit-returning-blank-page-no-html-at-all)

You must specifically choose "Static Content" under Common HTTP Features in the same Add/Remove Windows Features list to show the page.